# Add callback to jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am using a plugin kkcountdown for a timer on a website.

There is an annoying flicker when the page is loading when the timer is not set, so I hid the timer with css and I want to fade it in when the jQuery has run and the timer is set.

This is what I am trying to do now.

I have been looking at the jQuery queue function but have not had any luck with this either.

```
    $(".kkcount-down").kkcountdown({

        dayText : 'DAY ',
        daysText : 'DAYS<br>',
        hoursText : ' ',
        minutesText : ' ',
        secondsText : 'HOURS',
        displayZeroDays : false,
        oneDayClass : 'one-day'

    }, function(){

         $('#countdown').fadeTo(500, 1);

    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to initiate it on $(page).load() and then fade in on $(document).ready() ?

Comment: no I have not, I tried initiating on doc ready and then fade in on window load but that did not work. I shall look into page load now

Comment: You could also try the promise method suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the jQuery [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) method.

It could look something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".kkcount-down").kkcountdown({

        dayText : 'DAY ',
        daysText : 'DAYS<br>',
        hoursText : ' ',
        minutesText : ' ',
        secondsText : 'HOURS',
        displayZeroDays : false,
        oneDayClass : 'one-day'

    });

$( ".kkcount-down" ).promise().done(function(){
$('#countdown').fadeTo(500, 1);
});

});
```

/ ** SEEING AS THIS DIDN'T WORK FOR YOU **/

Adding a delay to the fadeTo can give you the effect you want allowing for the kkcountdown to initiate. A 1 second delay in my opinion doesn't result in much to the end user but it will give you your cleaner look. So jQuery would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // custom mod on line 92 by Roko C. Buljan & C Grimshaw-Jones
    $(".kkcount-down").kkcountdown({

        dayText : 'DAY ',
        daysText : 'DAYS<br>',
        hoursText : ' ',
        minutesText : ' ',
        secondsText : 'HOURS',
        displayZeroDays : false,
        oneDayClass : 'one-day'

    });


    $('#countdown').delay(1000).fadeTo(500, 1);

});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tLdZN/3/)

Comment: Hey I tried to implement this but It did not work, maybe it is the plugin. Still trying to figure out a method

Comment: Can you set up a basic sample of what you're trying to achieve on JSFiddle. I'd be happy to have a look on there if I can play with it a bit?

Comment: @ChrisG-Jones - I don't know if my brain isn't working today but I had trouble with this too. One solution is to just put a delay on the fade in event as I've put as an addition to my question. Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tLdZN/3/)

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing right now, It's just one of those things that will probably irritate me until I can figure out how to do it.

Thanks for your help :-)